# How to select multiple fields using "group by" in LINQ

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework-core

I've write this query

```
from table1 in _dbContext.INVHeaders
where table1.Date >= From.Date && table1.Date <= To.Date && table1.CompanyCode == Branch
join table2 in (from a in _dbContext.INVHeaders 
                select new { MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber })
on table1.MobileNumber equals table2.MobileNumber
group table1 by new { table1.MobileNumber, table1.TransactionNumber } into result
select new { Date = result.FirstOrDefault().Date, INV = result.FirstOrDefault().TransactionNumber, total = result.Count(), cus = result.FirstOrDefault().CustomerName };
```

and the sql query result of this:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT `i1`.`Date`
    FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i1`
    INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i2` ON `i1`.`MobileNumber` = `i2`.`MobileNumber`
    WHERE (((`i1`.`Date` >= @__From_Date_0) AND (`i1`.`Date` <= @__To_Date_1)) AND (`i1`.`CompanyCode` = @__Branch_2)) AND (((`i`.`MobileNumber` = `i1`.`MobileNumber`) OR (`i`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL AND (`i1`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL))) AND ((`i`.`TransactionNumber`
= `i1`.`TransactionNumber`) OR (`i`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL AND (`i1`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL))))
    LIMIT 1) AS `Date`, (
    SELECT `i3`.`TransactionNumber`
    FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i3`
    INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i4` ON `i3`.`MobileNumber` = `i4`.`MobileNumber`
    WHERE (((`i3`.`Date` >= @__From_Date_0) AND (`i3`.`Date` <= @__To_Date_1)) AND (`i3`.`CompanyCode` = @__Branch_2)) AND (((`i`.`MobileNumber` = `i3`.`MobileNumber`) OR (`i`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL AND (`i3`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL))) AND ((`i`.`TransactionNumber`
= `i3`.`TransactionNumber`) OR (`i`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL AND (`i3`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL))))
    LIMIT 1) AS `INV`, (
    SELECT `i5`.`Total`
    FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i5`
    INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i6` ON `i5`.`MobileNumber` = `i6`.`MobileNumber`
    WHERE (((`i5`.`Date` >= @__From_Date_0) AND (`i5`.`Date` <= @__To_Date_1)) AND (`i5`.`CompanyCode` = @__Branch_2)) AND (((`i`.`MobileNumber` = `i5`.`MobileNumber`) OR (`i`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL AND (`i5`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL))) AND ((`i`.`TransactionNumber`
= `i5`.`TransactionNumber`) OR (`i`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL AND (`i5`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL))))
    LIMIT 1) AS `amount`, COUNT(*) AS `total`, (
    SELECT `i7`.`CustomerName`
    FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i7`
    INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i8` ON `i7`.`MobileNumber` = `i8`.`MobileNumber`
    WHERE (((`i7`.`Date` >= @__From_Date_0) AND (`i7`.`Date` <= @__To_Date_1)) AND (`i7`.`CompanyCode` = @__Branch_2)) AND (((`i`.`MobileNumber` = `i7`.`MobileNumber`) OR (`i`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL AND (`i7`.`MobileNumber` IS NULL))) AND ((`i`.`TransactionNumber`
= `i7`.`TransactionNumber`) OR (`i`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL AND (`i7`.`TransactionNumber` IS NULL))))
    LIMIT 1) AS `cus` FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i` INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i0` ON `i`.`MobileNumber` = `i0`.`MobileNumber` WHERE ((`i`.`Date`
>= @__From_Date_0) AND (`i`.`Date` <= @__To_Date_1)) AND (`i`.`CompanyCode` = @__Branch_2) GROUP BY `i`.`MobileNumber`, `i`.`TransactionNumber`
```

But the result what **I expected**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `i`.`Date`, `i`.`CustomerName`, `i`.`MobileNumber`, `i`.`Total`  AS `total`
FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i`
INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i0` ON `i`.`MobileNumber` = `i0`.`MobileNumber`
WHERE ((`i`.`Date` >= '2022-07-01') AND (`i`.`Date` <= '2022-07-01')) AND (`i`.`CompanyCode` = '001')
GROUP BY `i`.`MobileNumber`, `i`.`TransactionNumber`;
```

The problem is that when I select columns, I need to use FirstOrDefault() to get required field which makes query complex. Can you please tell how I can make query mention above. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your intention and problem with more details? Do you have some example input and output as well so we could better understand the problem you are asking about?

Comment: I've no problem with input or output but the query is complex when its convert to sql. I want a solution which make this query using LINQ:                                                
 SELECT COUNT(*), `i`.`Date`, `i`.`CustomerName`, `i`.`MobileNumber`, `i`.`Total`  AS `total`
FROM `INVHeaders` AS `i`
INNER JOIN `INVHeaders` AS `i0` ON `i`.`MobileNumber` = `i0`.`MobileNumber`
WHERE ((`i`.`Date` >= '2022-07-01') AND (`i`.`Date` <= '2022-07-01')) AND (`i`.`CompanyCode` = '001')
GROUP BY `i`.`MobileNumber`, `i`.`TransactionNumber`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add missing fields to `GroupBy`

```cs
var query =
    from table1 in _dbContext.INVHeaders
    where table1.Date >= From.Date && table1.Date <= To.Date && table1.CompanyCode == Branch
    join table2 in (from a in _dbContext.INVHeaders 
                    select new { MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber })
        on table1.MobileNumber equals table2.MobileNumber
    group table1 by new { table1.MobileNumber, table1.Date, table1.TransactionNumber, table1.CustomerName } into g
    select new 
    { 
        Date = g.Key.Date, 
        INV = g.Key.TransactionNumber, 
        total = g.Count(), 
        cus = g.Key.CustomerName 
    };
```

Comment: group by without any need?

Comment: You have shown, probably MySql quirks, in standard you have to do grouping if you need these fields. Btw if grouping gives wrong result, i can rewrite query.

Comment: Result is accurate but I want to know is there another method to get access of fields after applying GroupBy?

Comment: There is no other effective way instead of additional CROSS APPLY/LATERAL JOIN. SQL Standard says that you have to include fields in grouping if you need them in result set. Some Database engines like MySQL can avoid such limitation but it has Undefined Behaviour.